# Show Dragged Element while Dragging in wpf

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

i am working on a wpf application, and try to implement Drag and Drop functionality, every thing is working fine except the visual view of Dragged element is not showing,

```
 void lb_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {

                e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy    ;

        }
```

I also set Allowed Effects here :

```
 DragDrop.DoDragDrop(_dragged, obj, DragDropEffects.All);
```

but still unable to view it.

Comment: This website is not here to teach anybody anything. We are here to help developer with particular programming problems. For example, you need to go off and find a tutorial on how to drag and drop with visual feedback and *if* you have a problem with a certain part of the code, *then* you can return here to ask a specific question. As it is, this question's scope is too broad and so I am voting to close it. There are many tutorials online, so I'll leave the search up to you.

Comment: @Sheridan i do search on net, but didn't found suitable code, thats why i asked here. i have already searched for my problem. If you have suitable link for my problem, that will be appreciated